# interaction terms in separate models?

Tags: regression, modeling, interaction

I'm doing a multilevel mixed model with three cross-level interactions in LMER. Do all three interactions necessarily need to be included in the same model or can I evaluate them in three separate models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check them in separate models, just like main effect terms. The only guideline is that the main effects that are involved in the interaction should be in the model (with rare exceptions).

However, if you are concerned about possibly inflating errors, running multiple models with interactions has the same issues as running multiple models without interactions.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that the interaction effects are highly significant in separate models (I include the main effects of the other interactions as well), yet when all three are included in the same model only one remains significant. What would be the better way to present these results, separate models or one model?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to convey and what the interactions are. The interactions may be co-linear with each other; they may be moderators or mediators as well.

Comment: It concerns three different moderators to the same main relationship. Two are highly correlated.

Comment: When two variables in a model are highly correlated, it's likely that there will be problems. So, I'd say use separate models, or just choose one of the two.